# How add Map in List data - dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to looping data in name and nation list to playerList, so i can get data in Expect Result

```
void main() {
  var name = ["Messi", "Ronaldo"];
  var nation = ["Argentina", "Portugal"];
  var playerList = [];
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> playerSingle = {};

  for (var i in name) {
    playerSingle['name'] = i;
    for (var j in nation) {
      playerSingle['nation'] = j;
    }
    playerList.add(playerSingle);
  }
  print(playerList);
}

// Expect Result
// [{name: Messi, nation: Argentina}, {name: Ronaldo, nation: Portugal}]

// Reality
// [{name: Ronaldo, nation: Portugal}, {name: Ronaldo, nation: Portugal}]
```

i tried to nested looping it but it didnt work

Comment: I want exactly same as below Expect Result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use for loop like

```dart
var name = ["Messi", "Ronaldo"];
var nation = ["Argentina", "Portugal"];
var playerList = [];
Map<dynamic, dynamic> playerSingle = {};

for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
  playerList.add({"name": name[i] ,"nation": "${nation[i]}"});
}
print(playerList);
});
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more on [dart.dev](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.6/dart-core/dart-core-library.html)

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way to do so is that

```
Map.fromIterables(name, nation);
```

Comment: i haven't try it, but thanks